Inconsistent behaviour for person mention in a status post on LinkedIn
I create status posts with an organization profile where I mention personal profiles.
I use LinkedIn API version 202307. 
In each post, I mention one personal profile. 
Some personal profiles are consistently published correctly. 
Others are consistently published incorrectly where the mention is in the form of @[Jeff Beck](urn:li:person:blAblAblA) instead of a beautiful highlighted text.
I can't see any difference between the personal profiles. It seems it doesn't depend on amount of connections. 
These users did not block their account from being mentioned. 
There's no mention of this subject in the API docs. 
What else could be the issue?
